# Need to combine JQuery files to save load time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the following JQuery libraries and I need to combine them in order to fasten up my web pages. Whats the best way and do some of them include the other ones in it, or can I find it some where, minified version that is.


JQuery.v1.6.4.js
jquery.tools.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js
jquery.alphanumeric.pack.js
jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js
hero_image_slideshow.js

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use httpcombiner if you are using asp.net. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HttpCombiner
Or else you can use yui compressor http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/
 http://www.refresh-sf.com/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Google Closure Compiler.

http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

Not only can you use it to concatenate the files for you, it will do other optimizations including minification, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use require.js and its optimizer: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

This is very related to a [similar question about combining jscript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511989/combine-multiple-jquery-script-files-into-one-js-file). A possible solution is [compressJS](https://github.com/dfsq/compressJS.sh), which uses the [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) in turn.

Answer (score 1):

1. Combine and Minify JavaScript so that it is a smaller download and
   runs faster
2. GZIP your JavaScript so it is a smaller download across
   the network
3. Place your JavaScript on a CDN such as Akumai, Lime
   Light or Cloudfront

I do this for my ecommerce development business with very speedy results.

Answer (score 0):

Is server-side combine an option? In that case, what are you running the site on? If you're using .NET, I highly recommend [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/).

For PHP sites, try [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/).

Scott Hanselman [blogged about a batch script for the same purpose](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx) using [AjaxMin](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/). You could include that as part of a build script, for instance, if you can't/don't want to combine the files at runtime.

One of the benefits of on-the-fly combining/minifying is that you can decide to turn it off for requests from your IP address, for instance, so that you will always be able to read the original script, if you're debugging live code.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the online tools at [jscompress.com](http://jscompress.com/) it seems reasonably good.
You can either copy > paste your code in, or upload your js files and it will compress them for you.