# Meteor: Aggregate multiple CSS and Javascript files into one on development server?

Tags: meteor

Meteor uses separate CSS and JS files on the development server and combines and minifies them on the production server. Is there a way to force it to combine and minify all JS/CSS on the development server (localhost), at least to check if the combined file works fine before deploying?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

```
> meteor run --production
```

[`meteor run`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorrun) now has a `production` flag:

```
Usage: meteor run [options]
Options:
  --port, -p    Port to listen on. NOTE: Also uses port N+1 and N+2.         [default: 3000]
  --production  Run in production mode. Minify and bundle CSS and JS files.  [boolean]
```

Comment: Impressive. The quality of the minification is impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Presently, no. You can `meteor deploy --debug` to leave the files unminified in production, but there is no 'combine but don't minify' command within meteor at this time.

Per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#commandline):

> You can deploy in debug mode by passing --debug. This will leave your source code readable by your favorite in-browser debugger, just like it is in local development mode.

If you simply want to combine multiple javascript files into one, [here are some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511989/combine-multiple-javascript-files-into-one-js-file).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my question wasn't precise enough. I want to combine *and* minify. What I mean is that I want to be able to test the production behavior locally, with all the files minified/combined as if it had been the case on the production server. There's got to be a special flag that is passed when meteor deploy is called that tells meteor: "hey, you are in production mode".