# Merge all javascript files to one file

Tags: javascript, html, merge

it's possible auto merge all javascripts on html page merge to one large javascript? (same for css)

for example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script src="/extern/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/extern/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/extern/form_validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/extern/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jsIndex.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple JavaScript files into one JS file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511989/combine-multiple-javascript-files-into-one-js-file)

Comment: for command-line solution: install `npm install uglify-js -g` globally and then do `uglifyjs file1.js file2.js  -o output.js -c -m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grunt-usemin (- https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) could help.

Comment: Thank you, it is great. Here is simple [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIbfDxF69c8)

Answer (score 6):

This one works on me

mainhub.js

```
function callAll(jsfiles) {
    var src = document.createElement("script");
    src.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    src.setAttribute("src", jsfiles);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(src);
}
callAll("your/path/to/a/jsfile1.js");
callAll("your/path/to/a/jsfile2.js");
callAll("your/path/to/a/jsfile3.js");
```

then all you have to call is the mainhub.js on your header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your/path/mainhub.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Gulp Can Help :

You can see the gulp tutorial and apply within your code.

Merge all js file into one. you can [see here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzD71yrOMhg)

Answer (score 1):

I hack together a script in Nodejs to do similar task

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function Do_Append(main,append_file){
    fs.readFile(append_file,function(err,data){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Read file"+append_file);
    fs.appendFile(main,'\n'+data,function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    console.log("Done "+append_file);
    })
}
var comp_list={
    'combine.js':['1.js','2.js','3.js'],
    'combine.css':['3.css','2.css','1.css']
}
for(var key in comp_list){
for(var idx of comp_list[key]){
    Do_Append(key,idx);    
}}
```

You Can Change the **comp_list** accoring to Your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require.js` and call it like this:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

And then in `main.js` you call all your scripts.

More info on that [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)

If you know to use npm then you can use different packes for gulp, grunt (like in 82Tuskers answer) or similar.

And if you want to do it with some online tools you can use [this](http://jscompress.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java platform you can use WRO4J. It can combine all JS into one JS file and all CSS into 1 CSS file. You can also combine few JS into 1 JS and few other JS into another combined JS based on your requirement.

configuration example

```
<group name="base_css">
    <css>/_ui/desktop/common/css/jquery.colorbox-1.3.16.css</css>
    <css>/_ui/desktop/common/css/jquery.ui.autocomplete-1.8.18.css</css>
    <css>/_ui/desktop/common/css/jquery.bt-0.9.5.css</css>
</group>
<group name="my_js">
    <!-- Custom ACC JS -->
    <js>/_ui/desktop/common/js/acc.common.js</js>
    <js>/_ui/desktop/common/js/acc.cms.js</js>
</group>
```

You can create multiple groups like above and use as per your requirement. There are plugins available for grail and groovy but I have not used those.

https://wro4j.readthedocs.io/en/stable/